# How can I run a loop of an input box that puts the data on a different row in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I have a spreadsheet that you press a Form Control Button, and that will prompt a Input Box that asks you to enter a name of non-stores item. Then if you enter in something in the input box it will put it in cell A19, then it will ask you for the lead time of the item and put that in C19. If you don't enter anything in the Non-stores Material input it will not bring up the lead time in put box.

What I want to happen is I press the button and it asks you if there is non-stores item, if you enter in anything it will assign that to A19 and then ask you for a lead time and assign it to C19, then loop back to ask you the name of the non-stores material and if you put in anything it assigns it now to A20 and then lead time to C20. If you enter in blank when asking for name of non-stores it will just end it. I also want this to be able to enter in some info and then later you can press the button and if there's some value in the A19 it will put it in the row below.

Here is my Current code:

```
Sub Non_stores_material_entering()


If ActiveSheet.Range("A19") = "" Then
NonStores = InputBox("What is the Non-Stores Material?")
Range("A19").Select
ActiveCell.Value = NonStores
Else:
End If

If ActiveSheet.Range("A19") = "" Then
Else:
LeadTimes = InputBox("What is the Non-Stores Material's Lead TIme?")
Range("C19").Select
ActiveCell.Value = LeadTimes
End If


End Sub
```

This is what it looks like for a visual purpose. [Non-Stores Spreadsheet Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CixlH.png)

Comment: So you really just want the data entry to start at the first non-empty cell below cell A18?

Comment: @dbmitch yes that's correct, and I want it to loop until the first input box receives blank entry

Answer (score 3):

A ['Do ... Loop Until'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx) will serve you here.

```
Sub Non_stores_material_entering()

Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change name as needed

Do

    NonStores = InputBox("What is the Non-Stores Material?")

    If Len(NonStores) Then

        Dim lRow As Long
        lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

        ws.Cells(lRow, 1).Value = NonStores

        LeadTimes = InputBox("What is the Non-Stores Material's Lead TIme?")

        ws.Cells(lRow, 3).Value = LeadTimes

    End If

Loop Until Len(NonStores) = 0


End Sub
```